# API call works from vscode runner but doesn't work from html

Tags: javascript, html, api, openweathermap

I'm trying to create a weather app in javascript with the open weather api.

I wrote a function getWeather() that is called when submitting a form.
But the function is stuck at the first fetch() call (I've tried to console.log to see if it enters in the function and I've seen that it is stuck here).

however, when I run the same function from the vscode runner, it works perfectly.

see the js here :

```
function getWeather() {
    let city = document.forms["weather-form"]["city"].value
    // let city = "New York";
    if (city == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apikey}`) // stucked here
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the html form :

```
<form name="weather-form" onsubmit="getWeather()" method="get">
    <input class="placeholder" type="text" name="city" placeholder="Search for a city">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Weatherize">
</form>
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help :)

Comment: did you get any error in console?

Comment: I do not get any error on google chrome console. But I get some strange errors in Safari : 
 - WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5500//ws' failed: WebSocket is closed due to suspension.
- Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Load failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I changed the onsubmit() with an event listener in javascript and it work perfectly now.

```
document.querySelector("#weather-form").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getWeather();
})
```